# How to install an application manually into the Application list

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

I am trying to install ZendStudio 8 (Eclipse based) on 11.04 and am kinda stuck at the part were I can get it into the Applications list.

ZendStudio prior to version 8 came with a magic .bin which installed it all no problems, but now it simply comes as a folder all set up to be run as-is. I have copied this folder to `/opt/ZendStudio`, and I can launch the program using `/opt/ZendStudio/ZendStudio` but in the Unity Launcher it shows up with a grey box and a big Question Mark as it's icon.

However, I'd like it to be show up in the Applications list so I can search for it and load it like a normal application.

I also want to Pin it to the launcher so it stays there the whole time, and I tried this with running it directly but it didn't work and it didn't load up the application icon.

Any ideas how I can finish the install so it is in my menus etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (from a terminal):

1. Create a new .desktop file:

   `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/zend-studio.desktop`
2. Add the following to that file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Zend Studio 8
   Exec=/opt/ZendStudio/ZendStudio
   Icon=/path/to/icon
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true
   ```

   For `Icon=/path/to/icon`: you'll likely find the icon somewhere in `/opt/ZendStudio`.
3. Save it and make that file executable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/zend-studio.desktop
   ```
4. Now browse to that file in Nautilus, double-click to start and then try to pin it to the launcher.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you, now it shows up in the Applications list :) Although it still doesn't have the icon in the Launcher

Comment: mmm... and the global menu doesn't work either. I think there might be issues with Eclipse and Unity which are causing this.

Comment: Followed these instructions for IntelliJ and it didn't work until after a restart.

Comment: @Josh What exactly didn't work? Running it, pinning it?

Comment: Hard to say, it froze while loading. I logged out and back in and it would launch from terminal, but not from the launcher. On restart it launched as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For the global menu, try this:

```
env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 ./ZendStudio
```

And there's also a bug report about it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/725331